# iOS - Programmatically added buttons with different target, always calls the last added buttons target

Tags: ios, objective-c

I added two buttons programmatically to UI as shown bellow.

Both buttons have different targets but somehow, they both call the last added buttons action.

For example for the code bellow both buttons calls 'btnResendCallAction' method.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
self.btnResendSMS = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.btnResendSMS setFrame:CGRectMake( edge, btn_y, self_w -edge*2, 150)];
[self.btnResendSMS setTitle:strBtnTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[self.btnResendSMS setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[self.btnResendSMS setTitleColor:[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom].tintColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.btnResendSMS addTarget:self action:@selector(btnResendSMSAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.btnResendSMS setEnabled:NO];
[self.btnResendSMS setAlpha:0.3f];
[self.view addSubview:self.btnResendSMS];


self.btnResendCall = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.btnResendCall setFrame:CGRectMake( edge, btn_y + 60, self_w -edge*2, 150)];
[self.btnResendCall setTitle:strBtnTitleCall forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[self.btnResendSMS setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[self.btnResendCall setTitleColor:[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom].tintColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.btnResendCall addTarget:self action:@selector(btnResendCallAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.btnResendCall setEnabled:NO];
[self.btnResendCall setAlpha:0.3f];
[self.view addSubview:self.btnResendCall];
```

Comment: Yes I did. Additionally if I change the order for adding buttons; I mean if I add btnResendCall button first then btnResendSMS, this time both buttons calls btnResendSMSAction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually with that code I would expect the buttons to overlap. But that is not evident because they have clear backgrounds and no borders.  So you think you are tapping button 1 but you are tapping the part of button 2 that covers it.

Give button 2, only, a red background color and this will be more evident.

Comment: I saw that I made a mistake while creating buttons layouts, thanks for catching it.